# Wallaby on a build server (CI)

Tags: tfs, wallaby.js

we are currently using [Wallaby.js](http://wallabyjs.com/) for javascript unit testing. Works fine and is great. But within our development pipeline we of course want to run the same tests on the build server - in our case a tfs.

- Is it possible to use wallaby on a tfs build server? Anf if yes how?
- If not, what is the way to go to run the wallaby configured unit tests on the build server?

As we used the karma test runner earlier, I tried to execute the new test configuration with it but then I get

> Can't find variable: wallaby

as in our main/ starting test file it is written

```
wallaby.delayStart();

require.config({
    baseUrl: 'app',
```

([Originally from a karma/ requirejs configuration](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html))

How to get around this?

Has anyone experience in this scenario?

Comment: At the moment, wallaby.js doesn't support CI scenario, you may subscribe to the feature request to get notified when it's implemented - https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/72

Comment: Thanks. I subscribed as this would be a great feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wallaby.js main idea is to integrate with editors, run tests for the code that you change and display the results in the editor. You can't use Wallaby.js in a CI build.

You may consider invoking other test runners, or use grunt/gulp task instead for javascript unit testing.

Comment: Using Karma now. Though, still struggeling with the fact that I have to maintain two files now.

Answer (score 1):

In TFS 2012 and later (might work in 2010 but not sure) you can extend the testing capabilities of the build system.

Check out these posts -

http://www.aspnetperformance.com/post/Unit-testing-JavaScript-as-part-of-TFS-Build.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah/